# How to configure m2e source editor to use WTP xml editor

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

From what I understand from this : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=561415, the source tab editor is configurable.

I have found no documentation on how to configure it.

Right now, it defaults to eclipse "stuctured text editor" which lacks decent XML support.
I have installed WTP xml editor plugin

How can I configure m2e to use it?

Comment: Since m2e 2.0.1 this is no longer possible: https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md#removed-legacy-wtp-sse-based-editor

Comment: Thanks. This editor for XML is bad news.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible as of v2.0.1 as per @howlger comment.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the latest version? The early version had a few glitches, but the current version is really good. There are some cool things that are only available in the new editor. Anyhow, if you don't like it, get involved.

Comment: just downloaded the latest eclipse for java dev.  same behavior.  and it does not seam to be m2e related. the generic editor crashes just trying a comment on any XML files, outside of the pom editor.

Comment: What do you mean with it crashed? Could you please link to the bug report on how to reproduce it? The Generic Editor outside of the POM editor is something different. Could you please also link to the m2e issues of what is your problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce, but while trying to reproduce, I get another set of problems. To truely illustrate I would need to post a video.

Comment: Using a freshly downloaded eclipse 2022-09  I created a simple maven project, with the simpler pom.xml (1 single dep) . Restart eclipse with -clean.  Open the pom.xml.  Now both keyboard shortcuts for comments  won't work. When I click "block" comments, from the menu, it does nothing. when I select my dependency and try to comment it out with "line comment",  the xml comments are not properly closed missing ">". opening it with Notepad++ shows the file is ok, so the "closing" comment "-->" is ok in the src file, but not in eclipse editor. Line numbers are broken at this point in eclipse editor

Comment: I get different  results, but every time the same : I was never able to comment a section of the pom.xml. I tried another scenario, did "ctrl-z" to undo my comment, got an Eclipse exception, with no stack, editor is crashed at this point. Cannot reproduce. But again... always XML comments related.

Comment: Also, when I type "<dep" and hit ctrl+space no code completion appears. The XSD is in the xml file, before all bells and whistles of this new editor, I expect basic XML code completion to work.  But when hit ctrl+space  between <version></version> I get a list of possible version.   It's like all XML editing features are lost, only "maven specific" code completion work.

Comment: the original question is was : How to configure m2e source editor to use WTP xml editor.   and this has been answered nicely. I will do a proper bug report, with MD5 checksum of my eclipse download, sample maven project, etc. to leave no place for interpretation

Comment: Please report issues only for the current or better for the upcoming version, not for outdated versions. Also consider providing a pull request.

Comment: see : https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/1093